# how to chop last n bytes of a string in bash string choping?

Tags: bash

for example `qa_sharutils-2009-04-22-15-20-39`, want chop last 20 bytes, and get '`qa_sharutils`'.

I know how to do it in sed, but why `$A=${A/.\{20\}$/}` does not work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If your string is stored in a variable called $str, then this will get you give you the substring without the last 20 digits in bash

```
${str:0:${#str} - 20}
```

basically, string slicing can be done using

```
${[variableName]:[startIndex]:[length]}
```

and the length of a string is

```
${#[variableName]}
```

EDIT:
solution using sed that works on files:

```
sed 's/.\{20\}$//' < inputFile
```

Comment: as a heads up, the `sed` solution will chop of on a per line bases so that `sed 's/.\{2\}$//' <( printf "1st line\n2nd line\n" )` will yield `1st li` and `2nd li`. Hence the strip to chop needs not to contain `<newline>` characters.

Comment: `sed '$s/.\{2\}$//'` will work for strings wich contain `<newline>` characters

Comment: This didn't work for me in Mac, but this was working https://stackoverflow.com/a/27658717/2704032

Answer (score 2):

using awk:

```
echo $str | awk '{print substr($0,1,length($0)-20)}'
```

or using strings manipulation - echo ${string:position:length}:

```
echo ${str:0:$((${#str}-20))}
```

Comment: `echo "${str::-20}"` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

similar to substr('abcdefg', 2-1, 3) in php:

```
echo 'abcdefg'|tail -c +2|head -c 3
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `${parameter/pattern/string}` syntax in bash, *pattern* is a path wildcard-style pattern, not a regular expression. In wildcard syntax a dot `.` is just a literal dot and curly braces are used to match a choice of options (like the pipe `|` in regular expressions), so that line will simply erase the literal string `".20"`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, but seems only one answer can be accepted, sorry:)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish the basic task.

```
$ str="qa_sharutils-2009-04-22-15-20-39"
```

If you want to strip the last 20 characters.  This substring selection is zero based:

```
$ echo ${str::${#str}-20}
qa_sharutils
```

The "%" and "%%" to strip from the right hand side of the string.  For instance, if you want the basename, minus anything that follows the first "-":

```
$ echo ${str%%-*}
qa_sharutils
```

Comment: `echo "${str::-20}"` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

only if your last 20 bytes is always date.

```
$ str="qa_sharutils-2009-04-22-15-20-39"
$ IFS="-"
$ set -- $str
$ echo $1
qa_sharutils
$ unset IFS
```

or when first dash and beyond are not needed.

```
$ echo ${str%%-*}
qa_sharutils
```