# Remove underscore before extension in strings

Tags: regex, bash, sed, rename

I have got strings like `tran_crossings_exp_.txt` and `tran_buildings_exp_.shp`
How can I write a bash function to test if the last character before the dot extension starts with an underscore and replace the underscore to have a name like `tran_crossings_exp.txt` I know how to get the basename and extension of the file in bash

I have done this solution but I am seeking a more elegant way which also check if the file indeed has an underscore and skips it if the name already is proper.

```
for file in `ls *_.*`;do ext="${file##*.}"; filename="${file%.*}";non=${file::-5}; mv ${file} ${non}.${ext};done
```

Comment: any attempts..?

Comment: check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658675/how-to-remove-last-n-characters-from-a-string-in-bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=tran_crossings_exp_.txt
i=${filename:${#filename}-5:1}  // Take the 5th char from back
if [ $i = "_" ]; then           // If it is an underscore
    echo "${filename/?./.}"     // Replace '?.' with just '.', this removes last '_' in this case (? means any character)
else
    echo $filename
fi
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/wDsAMD) you can test it

**Note**: this only works with `.abc` (dot and 3 chars) extensions

#### EDIT

To store in the same variable

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=tran_crossings_exp_.txt
i=${filename:${#filename}-5:1}

if [ $i = "_" ]; then
    filename="$(echo ${filename/?./.})"
fi

echo "$filename"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works if the file has only one dot (.) and any extension.

It uses string substitution.

One liner to see result of removing underscore:

`find . -name "*_.*" | while IFS= read -r file; do echo "${file//_./.}"; done`

Explanation: first find only those files which have an underscore followed by dot and then some extension. Then use string substitution to change `_.` to only `.`

To Rename:

```
find . -name "*_.*" | while IFS= read -r file;
do
mv "$file" "${file//_./.}"
done
```