# How to remove last characters from a string in bash using sed?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I would like to change all occurrences like "waaa", "wwwaaaaa", "wa" by trimming all the "a" in the end.

waaa > w
wwa > ww
waaaaa > w

I know how to find these strings in a text using regular expressions:

```
grep -nE "wa+" file.txt
```

I also know how to change one string in a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
s1="wwwwaaaaaaaa"
s2=${s1%w*}
echo "$s1 --> $s2"
```

(modified script from https://stackoverflow.com/a/27658717/5219155)

But I would like to use someting like

```
sed -E 's/wa+/ZZZ/' file.txt
```

where ZZZ is something that I need here.

```
sed -E 's/wa+/${$1%w*}/' file.txt
```

doesn't work.

Sample input:

```
Lorem ipsum wa waaaaaaa saaa dolor sit amet,
consectetur aw awwwwaaaa adipiscing elit
```

Desirable output:

```
Lorem ipsum w w saaa dolor sit amet,
consectetur aw awwww adipiscing elit
```

Comment: Using `gnu sed`, you can do: `sed -E 's/\bwa+/w/g' file`

Answer (score 5):

```
sed 's/waa*\b/w/g' file
```

```
sed 's/waa*\>/w/g' file
```

or using extended regex:

```
sed -r 's/wa+\b/w/g' file
```

---

`\b` and `\>` are word boundaries. For more information, see this regex tutorial: [Word Boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Comment: @maro then you should mention you want this for multiple words. Your input implies you have one long string.

Comment: I think I wrote it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

With bash, use [extended pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) to remove all the "a" from the end of the string:

```
shopt -s extglob
for str in "waaa" "wwwaaaaa" "wa"; do
    new="${str%%+(a)}ZZZ"
    echo "$str => $new"
done
```

```
waaa => wZZZ
wwwaaaaa => wwwZZZ
wa => wZZZ
```